# Screen time without "ignore limits" by using an iCloud account with a minor's age?

Tags: macos, ios, screen-time

I'd like to set up screen time limits **without** allowing myself to infinitely ignore the limits (because my spine is a stack of cotton candies and I can't trust myself to not just click ignore). Unfortunately I think because I am the iCloud family administrator account I always get to ignore limits, and I don't think there's a way to get away from that.

Can someone confirm that if I create a new iCloud account and set my age to be that of a minor, and add that account to my family, and then switch my computer and phone to that account, then I will have no way out of the screen time limits? Are there any unforeseen consequences you'd highlight for such a switch? Might certain apps or songs be age-limited so I won't be able to access them on that account? Can I still add my credit-card to the phone's wallet, when my phone uses a minor's account? I'm hoping to find a downside-free way of truly locking myself out of e.g. YouTube in the evening.

I'm also up for hearing other ways of imposing hard limits on myself, if there are other apps or systems you think I should consider (but please don't say "grow a spine" unless there's an app for that :)

Comment: You could ask someone you trust to create a "Screen Time Passcode" for you (They can be setup in Settings-> Screen Time). They'll keep the passcode safe, and you won't be able to ignore time limits.

Comment: …or there's https://selfcontrolapp.com

Comment: @Harcker I've used a passcode but I can still just bypass limits... that is, I can just click "Ignore limits for today", and no passcode required. Is that not your experience?

Comment: @Tetsujin oh neat, thanks! I'm hoping for a solution that'll also work on my phone though because that's where I'm the worst offender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harcker [wrote this in a comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438414/screen-time-without-ignore-limits-by-using-an-icloud-account-with-a-minors-ag?noredirect=1#comment630803_438414):

> You could ask someone you trust to create a "Screen Time Passcode" for you (They can be setup in Settings-> Screen Time). They'll keep the passcode safe, and you won't be able to ignore time limits.

Unfortunately that hasn't worked for me, as I've always gotten the option to ignore limits.

**But**, I just now noticed there's a "*Block at the end of limit*" checkbox in Screen Time, and that seems to do what Harcker says: At the end of the limit I can no longer delay the limit without entering the passcode!

[image: Screenshot of Screen Time setup showing the "Block at the end of limit" checkbox]